# Does letting services like PostgreSQL, Redis, MongoDB and Mysql run all the time eat up battery life and system resources?

Tags: macos, homebrew, services, automation

I'm a web developer and so I tend to run a lot of server applications on my machine to make local development easier.  Right now I use [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) to start the up as needed per project.  I do this in the belief that having them run all the time is just eating up resources since I don't always need them.  However I'm wondering if that is really the case or am I just being paranoid. Because having them run all the time would make things slightly easier.

Comment: Paging should take care of most of the memory, and OSX is kind of obsessive about putting processes to sleep when they aren't needed to save battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've switched to running the services all the time instead of using foreman and I haven't really had any problems with battery life.

I've also installed [LaunchRocket](https://github.com/jimbojsb/launchrocket) which makes it easier to actually manage those services from the Settings.app.  I'm very comfortable in the command line however this just makes it super easy to start or stop the services.

I'm also toying with the idea of using [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) to have start or stop some of the services depending on if I'm at work or not.